# Convert C struct with uint8_t *num to Go

Tags: go, cgo

C structure:

```
typedef struct info_s {
     int len;
     uint8_t *num;
}info_t;

extern int info_collect(int unit, info_t *info,
                        data_t *data);
```

Go Wrapper:

```
type Info struct {
    Len     int
    num     []uint8
}

//Method to convert C.info_t => Info

func (inf C.info_s) Info() Info {

   var tInf Info

   tInf.Len = int(inf.len)
   for i := 0; i < int(tInf.Len); i++ {
     tInf.num[i] = uint8(inf.num[i])
   }

   return Info{
     Len: int(inf.len),
     Info: (*C.uchar)(unsafe.Pointer(&info.num[0])),
   }
}
```

How do I access the `uint8_t *num` from go wrapper?
I don't think the method defined is correct.
Is the struct for num - (`num []uint8`) the correct way to access this?

Adding a missing piece of the puzzle. There is an API in C as well that takes the C struct as an input.

Now when I call this API, I get a runtime panic:

```
data := []uint8{1, 2, 3}

var inf = new(C.info_t)

inf.len = 64
inf.num = data

C.info_collect(C.int(unit), (*C.info_t)(unsafe.Pointer(&info)),
                            (*C.data_t)(unsafe.Pointer(&data)))

Panic: runtime error: cgo argument has Go pointer to Go pointer
```

Comment: You have to `make()` the slice before using it

Answer (score 1):

In Go, `num` is simply a slice of type `[]uint8` (or its alias `[]byte`) of length `len(num)`. To copy data from C type `info_t` to Go managed memory type `[]uint8`, write a Go `num` function:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "unsafe"
)

/*
#include <stdint.h>
typedef struct info_s {
    int len;
    uint8_t *num;
} info_t;
*/
import "C"

func num(info C.info_t) []uint8 {
    n := make([]uint8, 0, info.len)
    for i := _Ctype_int(0); i < info.len; i++ {
        u8 := *(*uint8)(unsafe.Pointer(uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(info.num)) + uintptr(i)))
        n = append(n, u8)
    }
    return n
}

func main() {
    test := []uint8{1, 2, 3}
    fmt.Println(len(test), test)

    info := C.info_t{
        len: _Ctype_int(len(test)),
        num: (*_Ctype_uint8_t)(&test[0]),
    }
    infonum := (*[1 << 20]uint8)(unsafe.Pointer(info.num))[:info.len]
    fmt.Println(info.len, infonum)

    n := num(info)
    fmt.Println(len(n), n)
}
```

Output:

```
3 [1 2 3]
3 [1 2 3]
3 [1 2 3]
```